# custom scalar type as input arguments in graphql

Tags: graphql, sangria

I defined a custom scalar type: DateTime (based on joda time library) in graphql schema. I see that in the Graphiql UI schema definition and a scalar line at the top of the schema definition.

however, I couldn't find out the syntax of including this as an argument in the query.

for ex, how do I send values of `MyDateTimeType` in the below query

```
query {
fetchData(key:"1", dateArg: MyDateTimeType) {
field1
}
}
```

Comment: my bad, It depends on how the ```MyDateTimeType```'s ```coerceInput``` method is defined (I'm using sangria). In my case, the ```coerceInput``` has a match case statement with ```StringValue``` case, so it worked when I passed a String to it. ```dateArg:"2019-05-30"```.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and accept them. This helps future users that have the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it depends on how the MyDateTimeType's coerceInput method is defined. In my case, the coerceInput has a match case statement with StringValue case, so it worked when I passed a String to it. dateArg:"2019-05-30"